# How to keep track of objects with the same name

Tags: c#, .net, windows

If in the event that there were three or more objects of a class e.g. three instances of Class1 named Class1Object. How could you keep track of all of these in a simple manner?

E.g. for example I wanted to do a Show.Form on the seconds instance / object of the class

Comment: Objects don't have a notion of names in .Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instances of objects are not named as such. Are you referring to the name of a variable you have reused three times? If so, and you need access still to each instance, you need to use three different variables or some sort of collection/array type.

Answer (score 2):

"Named" at what level?

They can't be named the same at the level of a given method or class, I'd be manipulating them through variables I'd named myself:

Class1 firstClass;
Class2 secondClass;

Though I wouldn't use `first` or `second`, but something related to by reason for having them exist in the first place. Just like `int id` and `int numberOfFailedAttempts` don't get confused.

The absolute last thing I would call an object of type `Class1` is `Class1Object`. I already know it's a Class1 Object, so that name imparts zero information to me. It's like calling a dog "dog", without the saving grace of being funny.

If I'd put them into a collection, then I'd either index them numerically in some way that makes sense, or with some other value that makes sense.

In all, I'm going to name things sensibly according to what I'm doing, not arbitrarily and then struggle to deal with a self-imposed lack of sensible names.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have three instances of a class with the same name (assuming you're referring to variable naming) in the same scope.

If you need multiple instances of a class, I would suggest one of the collection types rather than three separate variables for them:

```
// If you don't need anything other than an index
var objects = new List<Class1> { new Class1(), new Class1(), new Class1() };

// Collection keyed by a string
var objects = new Dictionary<string, Class1>
{
    { "Class1Object1", new Class1() },
    { "Class1Object2", new Class1() },
    { "Class1Object3", new Class1() }
};
```